# mySql LEFT JOIN not returning data as expected when Condition by ID php variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, left-join

When I use the PHP `$qs` variable in the WHERE condition it works fine but in `LEFT JOIN condition`, it's not returning any data.

Problem Line: `AND e.terms_id_user =`

**My Query: (Working)**

```
SELECT
    *,
    'users_staff_driving_license' AS driving_license_link,
    DATE_FORMAT(terms_date_created,'%a %d-%M-%Y %r') AS udate_created,
    DATE_FORMAT(terms_date_updated,'%a %d-%M-%Y %r') AS udate_updated
FROM users AS a
LEFT JOIN users_staff_details AS b
    ON a.user_id = b.users_staff_id_user
LEFT JOIN user_access AS c
    ON a.user_id_access_level = c.user_access_id
LEFT JOIN businesses AS d
    ON a.user_id_client = d.business_id
LEFT JOIN terms AS e
    ON e.terms_id_client = 'AA0000001'
    AND e.terms_id_store = '1'
    AND e.terms_id_user = 1001
    AND e.terms_datatype = 'users_staff_driving_license'
WHERE
    a.user_id = '$qs'
```

**My Query: (Not Working)**

```
SELECT
    *,
    'users_staff_driving_license' AS driving_license_link,
    DATE_FORMAT(terms_date_created,'%a %d-%M-%Y %r') AS udate_created,
    DATE_FORMAT(terms_date_updated,'%a %d-%M-%Y %r') AS udate_updated
FROM users AS a
LEFT JOIN users_staff_details AS b
    ON a.user_id = b.users_staff_id_user
LEFT JOIN user_access AS c
    ON a.user_id_access_level = c.user_access_id
LEFT JOIN businesses AS d
    ON a.user_id_client = d.business_id
LEFT JOIN terms AS e
    ON e.terms_id_client = 'AA0000001'
    AND e.terms_id_store = '1'
    AND e.terms_id_user = '$qs'
    AND e.terms_datatype = 'users_staff_driving_license'
WHERE
    a.user_id = '$qs'
```

Comment: What's the value of `$qs`? If it's not `1001` then those two queries are not equivalent.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Its value was mistakenly 1002. That's why I got no data. Thanks.